# How to develop facebook apps on windows azure platform?

Tags: .net, windows, azure, cloud, facebook-c#-sdk

What are the steps I need to do in order to host my .net written Facebook application on windows Azure platform?
I developed some facebook app already but I wrote them with PHP and hosted them on my own private web server.
I want to use [this](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/releases/view/68557) .net SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook C# SDK has Azure samples packaged with the download and on NuGet I believe. The developers also contribute to something called the [Azure Toolkit](http://azuretoolkit.codeplex.com/) which makes getting started in Azure easy.

[This post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ukmsdn/archive/2010/12/09/are-you-new-to-windows-azure-read-on.aspx) has some general Azure resources if you are unsure about general concepts.